# How to exclude child execution from parent

Tags: maven

I have multi module maven project, which include parent and its corresponding child.
like- 
parent
|
child 1
|
child 2
.
.

```
Now parent pom have following entries
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <modules>
   <module>
     child 1
   <\module>
    <module>
      child 2   
    <\module>
  <\modules>
 <\profile>
<\profiles>
<build>
<pluginManagement>
plugin for child 1
plugin for child 2
<\pluginManagement>

<plugins>
plugin for parent 1
plugin for parent 1
<\plugins>
<\build>
```

Now I want to exclude all child from build and don't want any execution of child pom.xml. I just need to execute plugins of parent.

is it possible if yes how? and if not then what's the alternate solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you like to exclude those childs? And what do you mean by `..don't want any execution of child pom.xml. I just need to execute plugins of parent.`?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I have some complex issues in my project that prevent me to do build child again, that's why I need to take them off in next maven build command. I tried " -P profileID " to exclude but it didn't work .

Comment: If you need to go a way like this i assume you are doing things wrong..can you explain what those mystical complex issues in your project are ?

Comment: sure, I have to sign all child jar's in install phase and place them in to new build directory and also keep unsined  jar with them in different directory and in same install phase i need to move both directories(signed and unsigned) to parent directory in target but unfortunately its not happen, hence i had reached a solution to copy all unsigned jar's in two different directories in parent target and then signed all jar's in signed directory by fire install command again. I don't know I am doing correct or not just suggest good way to do that

Comment: Moving files within a multi module build to parent directory target sounds wrong to me...By signing you are using https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/sign-mojo.html ? apart from that install is installing the artifacts only on your local harddrive which should be a problem...interesting is the case to deploy to a remote repository which means usually a corporate repository manager (like Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva)....

Comment: I am agree with you but my requirement is this right now, we are moving from ant to maven, that's why I need to stick with install phase of maven. And moving file in to parent is our requirement because in our organization convention its required.

Comment: you didn't even write the closing tag of XML right.... I think it is the obligation of questioner to make sure the question is written in acceptable quality

Comment: And, just a sincere recommendation: stay away from Maven if your project structure is so different from Maven's philosophy.  It may work but it is going to make your life difficult in Maven.  Maven may not be a suitable tool for you (given that you need to move files to parent... etc).  You may consider Gradle if what you are looking for is dependency management but not project structure convention of Maven

Comment: It's organization decision not mine, so I have to go with it.  any ways Thanks for comment

Comment: By adopting a tool, you do not only use the tool itself, you are adopting its design philosophy.  A bit off topic but if I am you, I will voice out the concern on conflict in convention in Maven's convention vs organization convention.  It is quite possibly someone else in your organization has already thought of it and have proper solution, instead of doing what you are trying to do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I got solution its easy to do that, just I was using wrong thing in given command. your pom.xml entries should be like this

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>buildProfile1</id> (added after )
  <modules>
   <module>
     child 1
   <\module>
    <module>
      child 2   
    <\module>
  <\modules>
 <\profile>
<\profiles>
<build>
<pluginManagement>
plugin for child 1
plugin for child 2
<\pluginManagement>

<plugins>
plugin for parent 1
plugin for parent 1
<\plugins>
<\build>
```

And your maven command should be like this :
**mvn install -P!buildProfile1**
*-P!buildProfile1* exclude your all module under this profile.